# How to extract data from multiple pages which have date in their url?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests, request

I want to extract content from a website where the link is as follows:

"www.example.com/getpublicreport?date=2021-10-01"

Using Requests what should be the code to extract data from multiple pages where I could navigate using the date in url.

For example if I want to extract data from date - 2019-01-01 till the current data how do I write code using request library to get the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can use datetime package :)

For example:

```py
import datetime

import requests


def extract_data(start_date, end_date):
    while start_date <= end_date:
        yield requests.get('www.example.com/getpublicreport?date=%s' % start_date.isoformat())
        start_date += datetime.timedelta(days=1)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    for r in extract_data(datetime.date(2019, 01, 01), datetime.date.today()):
        print(r.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

`www.example.com/getpublicreport?date=2021-10-01`

This is example of URL with parameters, [requests](https://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) does have `params` where you should deliver dict with key-value pairs. You might access this as follows

```
import requests
url = "http://www.example.com/getpublicreport"
parameters = {"date": "2021-10-01"}
r = requests.get(url, params=parameters)
print(r.url)  # http://www.example.com/getpublicreport?date=2021-10-01
```

If you want to know more about URLs read [RFC1738](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc1738).

Comment: Thanks for the info. But how do I extract particular data between two particular dates? For example to extract certain stock price from 2019-01-01 to 2021-01-01. How do i do this?